# How to use the "libtomcrypt" in C#

Tags: c#, c, crypt

I want to use the `libtomcrypt` toolkit in `C#` for Encrypt-Decrypt.
I'm not familiar with `C`, so help me.
The link for the toolkit: http://www.libtom.org/?page=features&newsitems=5&whatfile=crypt

Answer (score 6):

You need not use a C library for cryptography in C#. It has its own classes, providing everything you need. You just have to import [`System.Security.Cryptography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx). The following links will help you further..

[Code Project- Article on Cryptography in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6690/Cryptography-in-C)

[C-Sharp Corner- CryptoGraphy in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/1/60/cryptography.aspx)

Comment: the requirement provide Function prototype 
    bool Des_Encrypt(char *Out,char *In,long datalen,const char *key,int keylen); now i use the C# own classes to encrypt,but the result is different from their lib encrypt. they say their lib use C language, so i find the libtomcrypt to try.

Comment: I dint get you completely. Did you mean if you use C# function, the prototype will be different from what you want? If so, you can write you own function encapsulating C#'s function.

Comment: they encrypt the data,then i decrypt.but now the data that i decrypt is not except. so i suspense they used the des is different from the C#

Comment: des is standard and doesnt change with language.. you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: i use the online crypt tool ,the result also is not the excepted.I was desperate -_-